# season based database schema/design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a simple schema for a sports registration system till the concept of a season is introduced:

A player registers as part of a Team

A Team registers as part of a Club

A team plays in a Division

An Organization creates Divisions

This happens every season.  So I need a way to keep track of all of this every season. What would be the best approach here?  Should I introduce a "Season" entity and make many-to-many relationships between all the entities above as applicable?  Or is there a way to just "Archive" everything every season but also be able to pull all the season based data up on the fly (for reporting and what not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design allows teams to move to a different division from season to season, while not having to be re-created every year (though it doesn't allow for things like the Winnipeg Jets moving to Phoenix and keeping their old name with their historical season stats).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Organizations
(
  OrgID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
  -- , ... other columns
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Divisions
(
  DivisionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  OrgID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Organizations(OrgID)
  -- , ... other columns
  -- UNIQUE might be (Name) or (OrgID, Name)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Clubs
(
  ClubID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  -- , ... other columns
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Teams
(
  TeamID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  ClubID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Clubs(ClubID)
  -- , ... other columns
);
```

Now to keep track of seasons:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Seasons
(
  SeasonID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
  EndDate DATE,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL -- e.g. '1997-98' for seasons that cross Jan 1
  -- , ... other columns
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SeasonTeams
(
  SeasonID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Seasons(SeasonID),
  DivisionID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Divisions(DivisionID),
  TeamID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Teams(TeamID),
  PRIMARY KEY (SeasonID, DivisionID, TeamID)
);
```

You probably want constraints or triggers to prevent a team from belonging to more than one division in any given year.

Now you'll also want to denote a roster for a given season / team.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Players
(
  PlayerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  -- , ... other columns
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TeamRoster
(
  PlayerID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Players(PlayerID),
  TeamID INT NOT NULL,
  SeasonID INT NOT NULL, 
  DivisionID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (TeamID, SeasonID, DivisionID) REFERENCES
    dbo.SeasonTeams (TeamID, SeasonID, DivisionID)
);
```

You'll also want tables for schedules, standings, player stats etc... but that should be a start.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The way I did it was to just have a many to many between Divisions and Seasons.  This takes care of everything.  I'll still mark yours as an answer in case someone in the future needs to refer to it.

Comment: This was helpful for me. I just ran into a similar situation where I have a player table (that contains the TeamId) and I needed to introduce seasons. I believe I came up with the same structure as you did, so seeing yours makes me feel more confident it will work. Thanks

Comment: can you also share the schedules, standings, player stats ?